# FOR Loop Exiting Function Unexpectedly

Tags: node.js

I am at a loss for words trying to figure out why the code after my for loop will not execute. I believe that I must be missing something minor, but can't figure it out. The loop runs as expected but nothing is executed after it `console.log("Discount Section"); console.log(orderItems);`  isn't being processed or the code that follows it.

If anyone can help me understand why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated. I really don't want to create functions for the sections as this is already a function that is being called by multiple other functions.

```
const calculateTotal = async (order, next) => {
  let itemPrice;
  let total = 0;
  let discount = null;
  let orderItems = [];
  let orderTotals = {
    subTotal: null,
    discountAmount: null,
    shippingAmount: null,
    taxAmount: null,
    total: null,
  };
  // const taxRate = parseFloat(order.tax[0].taxSales);
  // const taxFright = order.tax[0].txbFreight;
  const taxRate = 0.0825;
  const taxFright = "Y";

  order.items.map((i) => {
    orderItems.push({
      itemId: i.itemId,
      sku: i.sku,
      quantity: i.quantity,
      price: i.price,
      lineTax: 0,
      fulfilled: false,
    });
  });

  const itemCount = orderItems.length;
  console.log(itemCount);

  //Check SKU for any price changes prior to order processing
  for (let i = 0; itemCount >= i; i++) {
    let itemId = orderItems[i].itemId;
    let checkProduct = await Products.findById(itemId);
    console.log(itemId);
    if (checkProduct) {
      let productPrice = checkProduct.price;
      let itemsPrice = orderItems[i].price;
      let isInStock = checkProduct.quantity >= 5;
      if (isInStock) {
        console.log("Item in Stock");
        if (productPrice !== itemsPrice) {
          orderItems[i].price = productPrice;
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Item " + (i + 1) + " - Remove Items from Cart & Notify User");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Can't find product");
    }
  }

  console.log("Discount Section");
  console.log(orderItems);

  //Apply Discount to Order/Items
  for (let j of orderItems) {
    let discountAmt = 0;
    console.log(j);
    if (discount.type === "Item" && discount.itemNum == j.sku) {
      if (discount.method === "Percent") {
        discountAmt = j.price * (discount.amount / 100);
        itemPrice = (j.price.toFixed(2) - discountAmt.toFixed(2)) * j.quantity;
        total += itemPrice;
        orderItems[i].lineTax = parseFloat((itemPrice * taxRate).toFixed(2));
      } else if (discount.method === "Fixed") {
        discountAmt = discount.amount.toFixed(2); //Could be an issue. Need to regex this to be numbers only
        itemPrice = j.price.toFixed(2) * j.quantity - discountAmt;
        total += itemPrice;
        orderItems[i].lineTax = parseFloat((itemPrice * taxRate).toFixed(2));
      } else {
        return next(new ErrorResponse("Unable to Calculate the Discount for your order. Please send an email to IT", 401));
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No Discount");
      itemPrice = j.price.toFixed(2) * j.quantity;
      total += itemPrice;
      j.lineTax = parseFloat((itemPrice * taxRate).toFixed(2));
    }
  }

 if (discount.type === "Order") {
    let discountAmt;
    if (discount.method === "Fixed") {
      discountAmt = discount.amount;
    } else if (discount.method === "Percent") {
      discountAmt = total * (discount.amount / 100);
    } else {
      return next(new ErrorResponse("Discount Method isn't set corretly. Please submit an IT Ticket", 401));
    }
    total -= discountAmt.toFixed(2);
  }

  console.log(total);

  //Calculate Tax for Order - Missing Discount for Entire Order
  if (total > 0) {
    orderTotals.subTotal = total;
    orderTotals.discountAmount = discountAmt;
    if (taxFright == "Y") {
      orderTotals.shippingAmount = 5.0;
      orderTotals.taxAmount = parseFloat(((total + orderTotals.shippingAmount) * taxRate).toFixed(2));
    } else {
      orderTotals.shippingAmount = 0;
      orderTotals.taxAmount = parseFloat((total * taxRate).toFixed(2));
    }

    orderTotals.total = parseFloat((orderTotals.subTotal + orderTotals.shippingAmount + orderTotals.taxAmount).toFixed(2));
  }
  return orderItems, orderTotals;
};
```

Comment: Do you really need the `async` and `await`?  If not remove them as they can have unexpected effects.

Comment: I need it to wait for the data to return.. I truly don't have this type of issue anywhere else in my application.

Comment: I have it hard coded, but I do have an API that is called for TAX rates

Comment: If I don't use the await it will not have the products returned from the DB. 61cb88d85f499fd4563e99d3
Item 1 - Remove Items from Cart & Notify User
61cb88f25f499fd4563e99d9
Item 2 - Remove Items from Cart & Notify User
61cb88d85f499fd4563e99d3
Item 3 - Remove Items from Cart & Notify User

Comment: Try logging `i` and `itemId` both before and after the line `let checkProduct = await Products.findById(itemId);`.  That will narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: `Calculate Totals
**Item Count: 3 **
** Index0 **
** Item ID: 61cb88f25f499fd4563e99d9 **
** Item in Stock ** 
** Index1 **
** Item ID: 61cb891e5f499fd4563e99e5 **
** Item in Stock ** 
** Index2 **
** Item ID: 61cb88d85f499fd4563e99d3 **
** Item in Stock ** `

Comment: It completes the entire loop, but exits the function like a return was provided

Comment: Even tho you can see the return later in the code and but the code between the loop and the return isn't executed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Had to update for loop to the following...

```
  //Check SKU for any price changes prior to order processing
  for (let oi of orderItems) {
    let itemId = oi.itemId;
    let checkProduct = await Products.findById(itemId);
    console.log("** Item ID: " + itemId + " **");
    if (checkProduct) {
      let productPrice = checkProduct.price;
      let itemsPrice = oi.price;
      let isInStock = checkProduct.quantity >= 5;
      if (isInStock) {
        console.log("** Item in Stock ** ");
        if (productPrice !== itemsPrice) {
          oi.price = productPrice;
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Item " + (i + 1) + " - Remove Items from Cart & Notify User");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Can't find product");
    }
  }
```